# Is "distribution" that important when submit app to AppStore in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

What happen if you don't create "Distribution" inside of the Code Signing window?

And what happen if you choose "release" instead of "distribution" under Archive Build Configuration box?

Because I just submit my app to appstore, and it doesn't seem to have any problem with it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **Distribution** is for Ad Hoc and **Release** is for for App Store. It's just a name, how it works depends on what code signing you choose.

If you go to **iOS Provisioning Portal**, select **Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution** and you can see they **duplicate** the distribution option from the release option.